# If statement on input select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, input, ruby-on-rails-4

In my form i have

```
<!-- Allow Custom Orders Field -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Allow Custom Orders?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :allow_custom_orders, [["Yes", 1], ["No", 2]],
                 label: false %>

  </div>
</div>
```

On my Show i want to check if `"Yes"` or `"No"` is selected and then show my button.

```
<% if @shop.allow_custom_orders = "1"  %>
  <div>
    <small>Need a custom order?</small>
    <%= link_to "Request Custom Order", "#",
                class: "btn btn-small btn-embossed btn-block btn-info" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

But this seems not to work, any suggestions ?

I'm new to Rails so bear with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it out :) was actually pretty simple

```
<% unless @shop.allow_custom_orders == 2  %>
```